# Performing Hotbackups of Gogs

Tags: git, backup, rsync, gogs

This question is related to this question which targets only the gogs-repositories component of gogs / git:

[Hotback of Git Server Using RSync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36946527/hotback-of-git-server-using-rsync)

Gogs also performs 'health checks' on the git repositories.  What do these health checks do?  Could they mutate the state of the repositories?  If so could that cause corruption is the repositories are backed up using RSync?

TIA,
Ole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I wanted to be able to perform efficient Cron based nightly backups while minimizing the chance of data corruption and being able to move the backup of site with encryption.  I also needed a time machine capability in the event that for some reason something something did get corrupted (Even though going back to a previous commit is an option as well).  Turns out duplicity has all of that built in and is a perfect fit:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DuplicityBackupHowto

So that's what I'm rolling with.  I'm also planning to switch off the health checks and perform them outside of gogs on a separate CRON job, but I'm still researching the recipe for that.  If anyone has tips please comment.